# Замена HTML-сущностей в строке

Tags: php

Есть строка:

```
$option = [&quot;213123123&quot;,&quot;213123123&quot;,&quot;213123123&quot;]; (Берётся из базы)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы символы &quot; были заменены на `"`

Comment: В массиве строки "213123123" или "&quot;213123123&quot;"?

Comment: А что эти сущности делают в базе?

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php

> `html_entity_decode()` является противоположностью функции `htmlentities()`. Она преобразует все HTML-сущности в строке string в соответствующие символы.
>
> Если быть точнее, то эта функция преобразует все сущности (в том числе все числовые сущности), которые а) обязательно верны для выбранного типа документа - то есть, для XML, эта функция не преобразует именованные сущности, которые могут быть определены в каком-нибудь DTD - и б) их символы находятся в кодировке соответвующей с выбранной кодировкой и разрешены в выбранном типе документа. Все другие сущности остаются без изменений. набор, связанный с выбранной кодировкой и разрешается в выбранном тип документа. Все другие субъекты, которые оставили как есть.

Answer (score 0):

Регулярные выражения тут не при чем, вам просто нужно обратно вернуть закодированные html сущности с помощью функции [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

**Пример:**

```
$str = '$option = [&quot;213123123&quot;,&quot;213123123&quot;,&quot;213123123&quot;];';
var_dump(html_entity_decode($str));
```

PS:

Подозрительная строка у вас хранится в БД. Думаю еще стоит задать вопрос о правильности хранения информации